# Why does this code for an ADC only return 4095 or 0

Tags: adc

I have set up a voltage divider with a [TLC2543 ADC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc2543.pdf).

Here is the code uploaded to my Arduino.

```
#include <SPI.h>

const int chipSelectPin = 53;
const int eocPin = 49;

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(chipSelectPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(eocPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(myVersion());
  delay(1000);
}

uint16_t myVersion() {
  uint16_t ad;
  uint8_t adq;

  digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, LOW);
  while(!digitalRead(eocPin)){}

  ad = SPI.transfer(00001000);
  adq = SPI.transfer(00001000);
  delay(10);

  ad <<=8;
  ad |= adq;
  ad>>=4;

  return ad;
}
```

Here is the setup on my Arduino:

[image]

The known resistor is 10k and the unknown resistor is Rf.

Following the voltage divider formula, v = 5 × (10k / 10k + Rf)

And since this is a 12-bit ADC the value on the serial terminal should show
V × 4095 / 5. Therefore 409610000 / 10000 + Rf.

However, while changing values for Rf, the serial monitor would print 0 if Rf was 0(just a wire), but for any other value of Rf it would print 4095. Can someone tell me why?

EDIT: Rotated Image, I tried adding comments, but i honestly am not sure what I am doing. Also Thanks everyone for taking interest in my question, and Im sorry for the late edit.

Comment: You need to check EOC output before starting data transfer. The 10 us delay in  readAdc() function was a poor alternative to this.

Comment: Also, you are trying to read 12-bit data while using two 8-bit transactions

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm sure you can make an effort to draw a far better diagram than that one. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: @Maple honestly I do not understand what I wrote myself and that is why I am asking for hell. How do I check EOC? There is nothing on the address map.

Comment: Thanks for the Welcome and thanks for taking interest in my question!

Comment: Connect EOC to GPIO and read it. As for not understanding the code, maybe you start there? Read TLC2543 datasheet and Arduino help. Otherwise it will be asking other people to do everything for you. We can help and point in right direction but the rest should be up to you. You already have everything you need in the comments above.

Comment: @Maple what do you mean by Arduino help? I will try connecting the EOC and try to make that work. Can you help me with the other comment you posted, about reding 8-bit data? Thanks!

Comment: [Arduino help](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/). TLC2543 can return 8, 12 or 16 bit data, depending on request (see datasheet). Arduino SPI can transfer 8 or 16 bit data, so you have to create request properly. The original code that you removed did this, your code doesn't.

Comment: I am assuming this is the line:ad = `SPI.transfer((chx << 4) | 0x0C);` that requests 12 bit data, can you explain how? Even when I try that code it still gives me either 0 or 4095. Can you also explain the meaning of X† on the datasheet?

Comment: Is my implementation of the EOC pin correct? Nevermind the Xcross. I read the Note in the datasheet.

Comment: Just a sanity check:  you DO have REF+ and REF- connected to Vcc and GND, right?

Comment: 0x0C requests 16-bit data, not 12. Your "00001000" is [0x200](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/constants/integerconstants/), which does not mean a thing. Your reading of EOC pin is correct, the timing of it not so much. Which of the transfer modes (figures 9 to 14 in datasheet) are you trying to use? Decide first, then make sure you read/write pins in correct order and at right time

Comment: I am using figure 9. Although I have to admit I failed the sanity check, and completely forgot to plug in REF- and REF+. That makes the original code that I did not write work. Thanks, @metacollin for the sanity check, and thanks Maple for teaching me about SPI, and practices for it. I needed this for a competition and now that it is working, the competition is more important for me, and once I finish the competition I will try to understand the working code and why mine did not work even after REF+ and -. Again Thanks all!